Plotly express is not plotting the chart in spyder
I'm using spyder 4.1.4 with Python 3.8.3 64 bit. I'm trying to plot a chart using following code
import plotly.express as px
px.bar(scores_df,x="Token Position", y="Score",color="Score Type", barmode="group", title="Start and End Scores for Tokens")

But it was not plotting the chart.
I have gone thorough Stack Overflow & based on Stack Overflow solution given here I tried this
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.express as px
pio.renderers.default = "svg"

fig = px.scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16])
fig.show()

But I still didn't get the chart. I also tried
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.express as px
pio.renderers.default='browser'

fig = px.scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16])
fig.show()

But still the same.
Can you please guide me to plot chart using plotly express in spyder?
